# References on analysis of obstacle problems and applications

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, numerical-methods

1. What reference books can I use as an introduction to the topic of the analysis of **obstacle problems**?
2. Where can I find information on obstacle problems that arise in applied mathematics, for example in **mathematical finance**?
3. Where can I find information on **numerical analysis** approaches to obstacle problems?

Answer (score 0):

The book **Obstacle Problems in Mathematical Physics** by Jose Rodrigues on the obstacle problem is very good and convers your first point, and if I'm not mistaken also the third. The second I have no clue.